# Is the extra 450 free dyno hours given by Heroku a one time offer?

Tags: heroku, dyno

New accounts receive 550 free dyno hours and one can verify their identity with a credit card for an additional 450 hours

- Is it one time?
- Or will I get 1000 hours every following month?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to replace search engines or documentation. Please read the friendly manual: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool https://www.heroku.com/free

Comment: And please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/354577) Asking a question here should be a last resort, not the first thing you try.